# how to show only even or odd rows in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a table MEN in sql server 2008 that contain 150 rows.

how i can show only the even or only the odd rows ?

Comment: Odd or even according to what criteria? You could mean A, C, E, ... or B, D, F, etc. Or do you mean row index according to the ORDER BY clause... but then what would you order by?

Answer (score 30):

Check out [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT t.First, t.Last
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY First, Last) AS RowNumber 
            --Row_Number() starts with 1
    FROM Table1
) t
WHERE t.RowNumber % 2 = 0 --Even
--WHERE t.RowNumber % 2 = 1 --Odd
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have a chance to create a query before I posted that... but I have extended my answer.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming your table has auto-numbered field "RowID" and you want to select only records where RowID is even or odd.

To show odd:

```
Select * from MEN where (RowID % 2) = 1
```

To show even:

```
Select * from MEN where (RowID % 2) = 0
```

Comment: YOu can never assume no gaps! There wil be delted records and transactions rolled back.

Comment: Never say never. Sometimes you can. For example if you have a static definition table. But the question is not clear to assume anything, so you're right.

Comment: Is this a [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217983/140226) filter? In other words, if your column was indexed in the table (e.g. an ID column) instead of computed by the query, would the query be able to use that index?

Answer (score 5):

FASTER: Bitwise instead of modulus.

```
select * from MEN where (id&1)=0;
```

Random question: Do you actually use uppercase table names?
Usually uppercase is reserved for keywords. (By convention)

Answer (score 5):

odd number query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM   ( SELECT rownum rn, empno, ename
           FROM emp
         ) temp
  WHERE  MOD(temp.rn,2) = 1
```

even number query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM   ( SELECT rownum rn, empno, ename
           FROM emp
         ) temp
  WHERE  MOD(temp.rn,3) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

For **even** values record :

```
select * from www where mod(salary,2)=0;
```

For **odd** values record:

```
select * from www where mod(salary,2)!=0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

odd :

```
select * from( 
SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS 'RowNumber', 
FROM table1
) d where (RowNumber % 2) = 1
```

even :

```
select * from( 
SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS 'RowNumber', 
FROM table1
) d where (RowNumber % 2) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY sal DESC) row_number, sr,sal FROM empsal) a WHERE (row_number%2) = 1
```

and

```
      SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY sal DESC) row_number, sr,sal FROM   empsal) a WHERE (row_number%2) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM   
  ( 
     SELECT rownum rn, empno, ename
     FROM emp
  ) temp
  WHERE  MOD(temp.rn,2) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Tablename 
where id%2=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is for fetching even number::
Select * from MEN where Men_ID%2=0;

Following is for fetching odd number::
Select * from MEN where Men_ID%2!=0;

Here MEN is your table_name Men_ID is the column in MEN Table.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
SELECT * FROM Worker WHERE MOD (WORKER_ID, 2) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a simple and straightforward answer to your question, (I think). 
I am using the TSQL2012 sample database and I am returning only even or odd rows based on “employeeID” in the “HR.Employees” table.

```
USE TSQL2012;
GO
```

Return only Even numbers of the employeeID:

```
SELECT *
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE (empid % 2) = 0;
GO
```

Return only Odd numbers of the employeeID:

```
SELECT *
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE (empid % 2) = 1;
GO
```

Hopefully, that’s the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch even records

```
select *
from (select id,row_number() over (order by id) as r from table_name) T
where mod(r,2)=0;
```

To fetch odd records

```
select *
from (select id,row_number() over (order by id) as r from table_name) T
where mod(r,2)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Oracle Database

**ODD ROWS**

```
select * from (select mod(rownum,2) as num , employees.* from employees) where num =0;
```

**EVEN ROWS**

```
select * from (select mod(rownum,2) as num , employees.* from employees) where num =1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**To select an *odd* id from a table:**

```
select * from Table_Name where id%2=1;
```

**To select an *even* id from a table:**

```
select * from Table_Name where id%2=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve by this
**Query To Find ODD Records**

```
/*Query To Find ODD Result using CTE */
WITH EVEN_ODD_RESULT AS
 (
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CountryID) AS ROWNUM
   FROM schema.Country_TBL
  )
  SELECT * FROM EVEN_ODD_RESULT
  WHERE (EVEN_ODD_RESULT.ROWNUM % 2) =1
```

**Query To Find EVEN Records**

```
/*Query To Find EVEN Result using CTE */

WITH EVEN_ODD_RESULT AS
(
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CountryID) AS ROWNUM
   FROM schema.Country_TBL
 )
 SELECT * FROM EVEN_ODD_RESULT
 WHERE (EVEN_ODD_RESULT.ROWNUM % 2) = 0
```

**Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

**SQL SERVER**

> Lets say you have student table with ROLL_NO column(int), and want to find the number of even and odd columns

***--SOLUTION OPTION 1-USING CASE IN NESTED COLUMN***,

```
SELECT Rolls, Count(Rolls) as Number
FROM (
    SELECT 
    CASE ROLL_NO % 2
    WHEN 0 THEN 'EVEN'
    ELSE 'ODD'
    END Rolls
    FROM STUDENT
    ) S --TABLE NAME TO IDENTIFY THE TABLE
GROUP BY Rolls;
```

***--SOLUTION OPTION 2-USING NESTED QUERIES***

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT WHERE ROLL_NO % 2 = 0) AS No_Of_Even_Rolls,
COUNT(*) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT WHERE ROLL_NO % 2 = 0) AS No_Of_Odd_Rolls
FROM STUDENT;
```

Answer (score -2):

for SQL > odd:

```
select * from id in(select id from employee where id%2=1)
```

for SQL > Even:

```
select * from id in(select id from employee where id%2=0).....f5
```