# how to get the even and odd column separately with separate column by query

Tags: sql

I have an input:

```
id
```

---

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I want get even and odd columns separately by columns in specified output like this

```
id col
```

---

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
7  8
9  10
```

here id and col are separate columns id contains the odd number and col contains the even number for specified input

Comment: If whatever you are working in supports modulus, that will be your answer for sorting.  if result mod 2 > 0 then it's a key, else it's a value

Comment: Are we assuming your table never has gaps in numbers? What if the next 2 numbers were 11, 13 with no 12?

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id, MAX(id) as col
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FLOOR((id+1)/2)
```

For IDs `1` and `2`, `(id+1)/2` are `2/2` = `1` and `3/2` = `1.5`, respectively, and `FLOOR` then returns `1` for both of them. Similarly, for `3` and `4`, this is `2`, and so on. So it groups all the input rows into pairs based on this formula. Then it uses `MIN` and `MAX` within each group to get the lower and higher IDs of the pairs.

Comment: what is your logic can you explain?

Comment: I've added some details. I thought it would be obvious if you know simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Joined the table on itself

```
select * 
from yourTable tA
left join yourTable tb on tA.id = (tB.id - 1)
where tA.id % 2 <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To show odd:

```
Select * from MEN where (RowID % 2) = 1
```

To show even:

```
Select * from MEN where (RowID % 2) = 0
```

Now, just join those two result sets and that's it.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2997480/1882535)

Comment: i want that in single query

Comment: How do you merge these to get the combine results? You need to join them, what is the join condition? (This is a rhetorical question -- the answer is basically the same as the `GROUP BY` condition in my answer.)

Comment: @Barmar you're completely right, I posted this answer before I saw yours. I can say that after a lot of years of experience with SQL (not a lot like yours, but still a lot) I could possible never come with such a easy solution like you did. Thanks for teaching me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL you can try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column  % 2 = 1 
            THEN column 
            ELSE null 
       END AS odds,
       CASE WHEN column  % 2 = 2 
            THEN column 
            ELSE null 
       END AS even
FROM yourtable
```

but not exactl as you ask

Comment: This will put them in different columns, but not in the same rows.

Comment: same i tried it before but i didn't get the exact answer